# Which website to use when choosing local US flights?

Tags: air-travel, usa, online-resources

Could you recommend a good website that allows comparing prices across different airlines for local US flights?
I have been using [Kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk) for a long time but I am wondering if there is a resource for flights within the US which gives more choice and/or cheaper options.

Comment: Define 'better'.

Comment: Presumably one that produces more flights, cheaper flights and shorter connections.  I too was wondering this...

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: I've edited the question to make clear what I mean by 'better'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Websites for comparing US air travel prices:

**Aggregators**

- [Kayak](http://kayak.com)
- [Hipmunk](http://hipmunk.com)

**Online Travel Agents**

- [Orbitz](http://orbitz.com)
- [Travelocity](http://travelocity.com)
- [Expedia](http://expedia.com)
- [Hotwire](http://hotwire.com)
- [Priceline](http://priceline.com)

**Other**

- Airline websites (e.g, [Southwest](http://southwest.com), [American](http://aa.com), [United](http://united.com), [Delta](http://delta.com), [JetBlue](http://jetblue.com), [Spirit](http://spirit.com), [Virgin America](http://virginamerica.com), etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Define "Better".

Kayak performs very well for advertised rates, so does OnCheapAir. You can use Hotwire/Priceline for bidding blindly (you give a day and a price, and you may get a flight on that day for that price, but you don't know at what time). Orbitz and Expedia provide good deals on packages.

Some airlines don't allow external bookings (like Southwest), so you have to go through them to search for their flights.

Comment: By 'better' I mean giving more results, say for some local airlines which are not taken into account by generic search engines.

Comment: Actually Kayak returns some flights for Southwest. However searching http://www.southwest.com/ gives much more results and better prices, so thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @vitaut they're all using the same search, in the end, IIRC the ITA (owned now by Google).

Comment: Some of them do tweak it a bit to try to cover the airlines that don't use the central reservation systems.  For instance, Kayak used to load the Southwest timetable into their system so they could show that the flights existed, but they didn't have pricing or availability.

Answer (score 4):

Google has just released ["Google Flight"](http://www.google.com/flights/) service last month ( Mar 2012 ).

[image]

Comment: Google bought ITA. See my comment above.